# How does this character get in to Wanda's Hex?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In the season finale of *WandaVision* Season 1 (*The Series Finale*) Vision meets

> The Vision - a revived and memory-wiped form of the original Vision who now looks a plain silvery colour and is out to kill Vision (Red-coloured version that Wanda created within the Hex)...

But what I'd like to know is how that character got in

> and presumably, *out*, of the Hex **unchanged**.

Given that we've seen other characters enter the Hex, it's not a stretch to believe that character *somehow* got in, however

> the others have all 'changed' in some form to suit the "show's" current aesthetic, but The Vision (White) remained exactly the same.

**How did this character get in to the Hex in that condition?**

Comment: I may be misreading your question, but it seems like you're differentiating between Vision and White Vision by saying that the original Vision was just called "Vision" while the new one is "The Vision". Just to be clear, original Vision's full name is also "The Vision". But everyone just calls him Vision. You can see "The Vision" written out on the house deed from an earlier episode, which original Vision bought before he died.

Comment: @Alarion Yes, in this case it seems that 'Vision' is the Red one that Wanda created within the Hex, and 'The Vision' is the silver/white one that was resurrected by SWORD. You can see that Wanda always calls him "Vision". I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 10):

We’re not shown exactly how but there seem to be a few ways he could break in without changing. The simplest I’d imagine would be phasing through. If he phased his body he could just pass through without needing to be re-written. It seems to be the act of passing the barrier that causes any rewrites not simply being inside the hex. For example, see the “bee keeper” and then later on the SWORD agents who enter through the gaps and are never rewritten.

He also has an energy beam of sorts, similar to the Vision’s previous Mind Stone energy beam. He could have used that to break the hex barrier down, along with his superhuman strength, and pass through a gap.

Though I’d argue the above isn’t strictly necessary. The hex was created by Wanda in grief for Vision so they could be together again. It might simply be that Vision is just something that requires no change. That’s how the drone went through the barrier and was able to pass unchanged.

> **Monica:** What happens if we send something in that requires no change?
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 5, “On a Very Special Episode”</sub>

Note on a similar line to above Jimmy said he couldn’t get in because the “town” didn’t want him to enter. Presumably the hex is perfectly fine with the actual Vision entering.

> **Monica:** Why haven't you gone inside to investigate?
>
> **Jimmy:** 'Cause it doesn't want me to. You can feel it too, can't you? Nobody's supposed to go in.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 4, “We Interrupt This Program”</sub>